# menuconfig window pop-up issue in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am building kernel image for arm based board in linux (3.13) host. I have followed the below steps :

```
1) Downloaded Legato Distribution Source Package 
2) tar -xvjf Legato-Dist-Source-mdm9x15-SWI9X15Y_07.10.04.00.tar.bz2
3) cd yocto
4) export LEGATO_BUILD=0
5) make image_bin
6) . ./poky/oe-init-build-env
7) cd …/build_bin
8) bitbake linux-yocto -c kernel_configme -f
9) bitbake linux-yocto -c menuconfig
```

When i do 9th step i.e, menuconfig to configure the kernel, configuration window will come and immediately vanishes. So i’m not able to configure the kernel.

menuconfig will work perfectly in my host linux machine by poping a window to set the configurations.

Am i done anything wrong? Please help me to get the window popup to configure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a "special" shell? It failed for me one time because my default shell window was too small. Try to use the basic shell.

Comment: what is special shell here? I am using big shell only.

Comment: If you are using ubuntu reconfigure bash ( sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash)
press "No" when prompted.

Comment: Clean the kernel using the command `bitbake -c clean linux-yocto` and then bitbake the kernel forcefully using `bitbkae -c compile linux-yocto -f`. Next to that, try `bitbkae -c menuconfig linux-yocto`. This should hopefully work out.

Answer (score 0):

For this version you need to be sure you are using a:

1. **Ubuntu Linux version 14.04.X**
2. Besides you must use bash instead dash, check this  with the command "**which bash | xargs ls -la**"